# How to bring application to foreground using Spotlight/keystrokes (named windows/named applications)?

Tags: spotlight, mission-control

I can open Spotlight with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>. That's nice, and I can search for the program I want in the foreground, but sometimes the application doesn't come to the foreground. Is there some series of keystrokes I can use to bring an application to foreground?

Sometimes visually searching for it in Mission Control is too hard when you have 10+ applications running. I'd rather just type.

Spotlight generally works, but if you have more than one open application window it doesn't quite work. Is there a way to put *names* on windows and then open them by *name*?

Comment: Why do you think you need to run multiple copies of the same app? The OS will consider them essentially 'the same thing' & you cannot differentiate using this method.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to put *names* on windows and then open them by *name*?

No, there is no built-in mechanism in macOS to assign names to different windows of an app and access it by names.

> Spotlight generally works, but if you have more than one open application window it doesn't quite work.

When using Spotlight to search and launch an already running app, the window will be shown in the foreground in the following cases:

1. There's only a single open app window.
2. The app window(s) are not minimized, but hidden using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.

   If the app is hidden while none of the window is minimized, invoking app name will show all of them.
3. If the app window(s) are minimized, only one of them is shown in the foreground.

   The other open and minimized windows can be brought to foreground using either one of the following methods:

   - Right click on the Dock icon for the app and select the window. The minimized windows are shown with a leading ◆ icon in the context menu.
   - Bring the app to foreground normally using Spotlight. Now use the Application Windows Hot Corner action to see just the app windows, maximized or minimized in a Mission Control like view.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are two keyboard shortcuts to keep mind for navigating apps and their windows:

1. Use <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to bring up the App Switcher and continue pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move left to right in the list, or press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key too in conjunction  with <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to move from right to left.
2. Once the target app is selected and comes forward, use <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> to go through the app's windows. Use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key too in conjunction  with <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> to move backwards through the app's windows.

---

Note that the <kbd>`</kbd> (Grave Accent) key on a US English keyboard is usually paired with the **~** (tilde) key.

Comment: the grave accent is also known as a backtick tmk

Comment: @Alexander Mills, Yes, I forgot that and was going by what came up in Character Viewer (Emoji & Symbols).

Comment: I'd like to add that using Command + Backtick, you can not switch to a window that's minimized.

Comment: @Nimesh Neema, Yes this is true. BTW This answer is meant to be more informational the and not necessarily resolve all aspects of the question.