# Rename application so I can search for it with spotlight

Tags: applications, spotlight, macos, application-switcher

Is there a way to rename an application so I can search for it with Spotlight?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I don't see a rename option there.

Comment: This sounds a bit like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) - why do you think the solution to your issue is to rename it? What is your *actual* issue? maybe there's another way. [Renaming apps doesn't always do what you'd think, but that's for a different question]

Comment: OK, I found the X to this Y - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360747/how-to-bring-application-to-foreground-using-spotlight-keystrokes-named-windo Renaming an app you are trying to run multiple copies of will not help you. The OS isn't really looking at the name. The solution is to not try to do this.

Comment: Let's get back to the problem.  Why the app isn't found by spotlight. What folder is the app in?  Have you excluded this folder from the spotlight search? Look in apple icon > system preferences > spotlight

Comment: I have some websites that are packaged into applications using a chrome extension and I want to name them - this: https://applicationize.me/now which I found via https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/website-desktop-mac-app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select Show in Finder
- Select the name of the app
- Press enter
- Type the new name

Bob’s your uncle. You might need to quit the app before the rename works or shows in the dock, though.

Comment: This will work for some but not all applications.  It depends on how the app is implemented.

Comment: For sure @historystamp - we’d need a follow on question naming the app in that case.